# building android application within java program

Tags: java, android, ant

I am trying to build an android apk using ant from within java.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c",   "D:\\Softwares\\Android\\tools\\android.bat update project -p ArithmeticAndroid"});
          pb.directory(new File("D:\\test\\ArithmeticAndroid"));
Process p = pb.start();
int exitStatus = p.waitFor();
```

This is my code snippet,exitStatus is 0 but android.bat has no effect on the ArithmeticAndroid,the projec I am trying to build.I am really stuck in this.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm gonna do everyone a favor and ask "why?"

Comment: @Shark Because this is needed for an academic project.The project topic is android appmaker.

Comment: So your mentor/teacher told you to invoke batch scripts from cmd.exe from Java to build android apps? Why not just invoke "make" and call it there? Or are you building an app that will generate the appropriate Android.mk file and call make on that?
What do you have so far? Whats your idea on 'building android apps' ?? Android make system is straightforward but can sometimes be a pain to work with. Do you even know the procedure to build android apps?

Comment: @Shark i have a sample android project i am able to customize its strings.xml and then build the apk file.I am using ant to build that.any way thanks for replying i got it working.it was a small mistake,may be you haven't noticed that

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", "D:\\Softwares\\Android\\tools\\android.bat","update","project","-p","."});
pb.directory(new File("D:\\Final-App-   Templates\\"+ftm.getpName()));
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```